# How to enable digit grouping (thousands separators) in calculator?

Tags: release-loki, calculator

Is it possible? Language packs are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no possibility to do this because this is not something implemented in the source of `pantheon-calculator`.

You can always file a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos) or even a [bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary/bounties), but it might not meet the goals of the developers who want to keep things simple.